# How to add keyboard shortcut (accelerator) for wireshark lua plugin?

Tags: plugins, lua, wireshark

I have created a wireshark plugin using lua, which currently shows up under Tools->my_plugin

I want to know, if there is a way by which I can assign a keyboard shortcut to it, so that users dont have to go through menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do that currently. You could submit a patch to allow `register_menu` to take a shortcut key.

For others, documentation of `register menu`:
https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/GUI#register_menu.28name.2C_action_.5B.2Cgroup.5D.29